# Deducing the return type of a map with varying value types

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I have the following code

```
#include <boost\any.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <string>

enum class tags { int_param, string_param };

class Parameters
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void set(tags key, T value)
    {
        map_[key] = value;
    }

    template <typename T>
    T get(tags key)
    {
        return boost::any_cast<T>(map_[key]);
    }

private:
    std::map<tags, boost::any> map_;
};

int main()
{
    Parameters params;

    params.set(tags::int_param, 42);
    params.set(tags::string_param, "it works!");

    int int_par = params.get<int>(tags::int_param);
    std::string string_par = params.get<std::string>(tags::string_param);

    std::cout << "Channel: " << int_par << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Filename: " << string_par << std::endl;
}
```

This code works however I do not like having to supply the templated type and I would like, if at all possible, to be able to retrieve something from the map without having to supply the template type i.e.

```
int int_par = params.get(tags::int_param);
```

instead of

```
int int_par = params.get<int>(tags::int_param);
```

I understand by using boost::any that we need to cast to a supplied type from the any type but is there a way we can do it without having to supply it ourself and can we instead deduce it some other way>

Comment: Your second example using `std::string` is not supposed to compile is it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the compiler must know the template type during compile time. You store the params during runtime so I don't think there's a way to deduce the parameter type.

Comment: @user2079303 Well, we can deduce them from the declaration of the value that is being constructed.

Comment: @pmr, I don't quite get that but that's ok. @const_ref (or anyone), I'm curious, what advantages does this class have as opposed to `struct Parameters { int int_param; std::string string_param; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change tags from enum values to structs you can achieve the desired behavior and even other good features, such as type safety and that our use of any_cast won't ever throw.

By using structs we can define simple traits to get each tags value type, such as

```
enum class tag_id
{
  int_param; // Id which represents int_param tag on std::map
}

struct int_param_t
{
  using value_type = int;
  static const tag_id id;
};
const tag_id int_param_t::id = tag_id::int_param;
```

Now we can use this traits to achieve your desired syntax

```
template< typename Tag >
auto get( Tag ) -> typename Tag::valye_type
{
  return boost::any_cast<typename Tag::valye_type>(map_[Tag::id]);
}

// ...

int         a = parameters.get( int_param_t{} ); // Ok, returns int.
std::string b = parameters.get( int_param_t{} ); // Error, int is not convertible to std::string.
```

As a bonus we can use this traits to ensure only types convertable to the correct type are used with `set` function

```
template< typename Tag >
void set( Tag, typename Tag::value_type value )
{
  map_[Tag::id] = value;
}

// ...

parameter.set( int_param_t{},        0 ); // Ok, 0 is convertible to int.
parameter.set( int_param_t{}, "string" ); // Error, const char[] is not convertible to int.
```

To make it a little bit prettier, I would also define some alias and constants such as

```
// Helper alias to avoid writing typename everywhere.
template< typename T >
using param_type = typename T::value_type;

// Used to avoid having to create tag objects every function call.
constexpr int_param_t int_param{};
```

And here is the final product

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <string>

namespace tags
{
    enum class tag_id
    {
        int_param,
        string_param
    };

    struct int_param_t
    {
        using value_type = int;
        static const tag_id id;
    };
    const tag_id int_param_t::id = tag_id::int_param;

    constexpr int_param_t int_param{};

    struct string_param_t
    {
        using value_type = std::string;
        static const tag_id id;
    };
    const tag_id string_param_t::id = tag_id::string_param;

    constexpr string_param_t string_param{};
}

// Helper alias to avoid writing typename everywhere.
template< typename T >
using param_type = typename T::value_type;

class Parameters
{
public:
    template <typename Tag>
    void set(Tag, param_type< Tag > value)
    {
        map_[Tag::id] = value;
    }

    template <typename Tag>
    auto get(Tag) -> param_type< Tag >
    {
        return boost::any_cast< param_type< Tag > >(map_[Tag::id]);
    }

private:
    std::map<tags::tag_id, boost::any> map_;
};

int main()
{
    Parameters params;

    params.set(tags::int_param, 42);
    params.set(tags::string_param, "it works!");

    int int_par = params.get(tags::int_param);
    std::string string_par = params.get(tags::string_param);

    std::cout << "Channel: " << int_par << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Filename: " << string_par << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Looks brilliant but I get a compilation error maybe due to using Visual Studio?

Comment: @const_ref The code contained some bugs which are now fixed.
That being said, Visual Studio may not be able to compile this code, but Clang can.

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. You still have to say `int` at least twice (it's just masked as a param) unless you are using `auto` and I thought OPs intention was to write it only once. The solution is also rather hard to extend for new types.

Comment: OPs requests specifically for a way to avoiding explicit template parameters at client code, as in set and get functions.

I do believe my proposal gives a better interface to the end user of the class than the other answers as it is type safe, don't rely on run time checks for error, avoid explicit template parameters and interacts well with type deduction scenarios.

Example:
    auto a = parameters.get( tags::int_param ); // Deduces auto correctly to be of int type, avoiding possibly multiple calls to boost::any_cast or boost::bad_any_cast being thrown far away from call site.

Comment: Although I do agree that it's a little bit harder to work with new tags with my solution, I think the advantages easily outweighs this price.

Comment: I really like it and the type safety it offers is brilliant. It also solves my main issue of having to declare the template type in the client code and as stated I can simple say auto var = get(...). In the client code is not as black/white as int_param, string_param etc, this was just an example on how I would like the code to behave

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to deduce anything from an `any` but there might be a chance to deduce something from the declaration. As your code already throws when `any_cast` fails, I suppose this is not an issue for you.

You could extend (really a bad idea to due to the missing virtual destructor) `boost::any` or wrap it  and provide a templated conversion operator.

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct converting_any {
  converting_any(boost::any* a) : a(a) {}

  template<typename T>
  operator T() { return boost::any_cast<T>(*a); } // dereference to get the throwing version
private:
  boost::any* a; // wrapped any
};

int main()
{
  int i = 3; std::string j = "asddf";
  boost::any a = i;

  int i2 = converting_any(&a);
  try {
    std::string j2 = converting_any(&a);
  } catch(...) {
    std::cout << "Failure." << std::endl;
  }

  a = j;
  std::string j3 = converting_any(&a);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could return a reference wrapper which postpones the cast until its needed:

```
struct converter {
    converter(boost::any & any) : any(any) {}

    template <typename T>
    operator T() {return boost::any_cast<T>(any);}

    boost::any & any;
};

converter get(tags key)
{
    return map_[key];
}
```

The template argument can be deduced from the type being converted to, so your `int` example will work without an explicit template argument.

Note that, as with your version, this will fail if the template parameter doesn't match the variant's type, as demonstrated in your example when attempting to convert `const char *` to `std::string`.

Comment: Incredible how two people can come up with almost the exact same code.